Circuit design for a timer and relay
I'm designing a timer circuit that detects white cards with black stripes, which needs to be inserted in a specific position to activate. The black stripe sensor must remain disabled when the card is inserted correctly, as the infrared will not reflect black. I need help wiring this Q1 transistor so that when there is voltage at its base (in this case the card would be in an incorrect position), the timer and relay cannot be turned on. All the ways I tried didn't work. Other suggestions to improve the circuit are also welcome.



bit surprised – usually, these black stripes are magnetic material with self-clocking data on it, and you could simply detect insertion mechanically with a limit switch, and orientation with a simply high-pass filter on the output on the (amplified) output of a magnetic sensor.

Thanks for your time Marcus! In wich frequency should I make my high-pass filter?

that depends on the slowest insertion you still want to detect. This can span orders of magnitude, so I'd encourage you to just kind of try. As a rule of thumb: track 1 on credit cards contains about 8 bits per mm, so if you allow for an insertion as slow as 50 mm / 4s, you'd still end up with around a hundred transitions per second. I'd honestly just salvage a magnetic read head from a discarded audio cassette player, attach it to the microphone input of my laptop, make a recording as I push a payment card by it and look at the signal to figure out specifics.

I recommend that you replace the LM2904 op-amps with comparators. (They'll work better, don't risk latch-up in saturation.) Many comparators have open-collector or open-drain outputs and this would allow you to tie the two comparator outputs to the one pull-up resistor to give an OR function.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Simplified comparator OR gate.
You would then need to check the logic of your comparator inputs to ensure that the outputs are pulled high by R1 when both conditions are met.

A comparator like a LM393? For testing purposes the 2904 should work, right? I just have LM2904 and LM358 right now

The conditions I need to turn Q1 on are CMP1=1 and CMP2=0

(1) No, op-amp outputs can't be wired in parallel. The comparators with open-collectors can. (2) No to turn on Q1 you need CMP1 = 1 and CMP2 = 1. Both have to have their open-collector outputs turned off so that R1 can pull the base of Q1 high. If either is low then Q1 and the relay will be off.
